# ajax sends POST twice, receiving double/repetitive results from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

i found out my JS sends POST method twice to my PHP file, thats why i keep getting double/repetitive results from my PHP.

[image]

This JS event, upon `.keyup()` will execute an ajax.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    var getUrl = $('#url');
    var youtube = regex here
    var web = regex here    

        getUrl.keyup(function() {

        if  (youtube.test(getUrl.val())) {
        var youtube_url = getUrl.val().match(youtube)[0];
        $.ajax ({
                type:"POST",
            url:"getyoutube.php",
            data: {youtube_url:youtube_url},
            success: function(html) { $('.echotest').append(html); }
        }); }

    else if (web.test(getUrl.val())) {
        var extracted_url = getUrl.val().match(web)[0];                 
                    $.post("curl_fetch.php?url="+ extracted_url, {
                }, function(response){
           $('#loader').html($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
           $('#cur_image').val(1);
        });} 
    }); 
});
```

the data will be received by `getyoutube.php` and should only print json result of a particular youtube video **once**.

```
 //some code ommitted
 $youtube ="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$matches[0].'?v=2&alt=jsonc";
 $curl = curl_init($youtube);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $return = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 $test = json_decode($return, true);
 print_r($test);
```

i cant seem to figure out why my AJAX post keeps sending POSTS method twice

Comment: make sure you do not press more than one key periodically...

Comment: There's no reason to even have a PHP script. YouTube's API accepts JSONP callbacks.

Comment: i faced this problem too. but mine was only in chrome. in FF, opera only single request. couldn't find any solution so i changed the whole design. -_-

Comment: Indeed, also note that keys like "tab" and "ctrl" etc. are alzo keys even if they don't directly change something.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

1) Make sure you bind and unbind your key up event

2) Use a global variable to make sure only one ajax request gets sent at once

i.e.:

```
var ajaxrequest = false; //GLOBAL

function getyoutubedata(){

  if(ajaxrequest != false){
     return;  
  }

  ajaxrequest = $.ajax ({
        type:"POST",
        url:"./includes/getyoutube.php",
        data: {youtube_url:youtube_url},
        success: function(html) { $('.echotest').append(html); ajaxrequest = false; }
  });

}
```

Btw thing to note the youtube api supports jsonp callbacks so you might want to consider doing this through that

3) Try to check if the content of the input field has changed even before calling the above function

Answer (score 0):

You should show us the code with the `.keyup()` event, probably that's the place of an error. The event handler could execute a wrapper function for the ajax, instead of the ajax directly. For example, if you the keyup event is triggered, try to check if the input content has changed. If so, run ajax, if not - do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

coverted this

```
 $.ajax ({
       type:"POST",
       url:"getyoutube.php",
       data: {youtube_url:youtube_url},
       success: function(html) { $('.echotest').append(html); }
        }); }
```

to this.

```
$.post("./includes/getyoutube.php?url="+ youtube_url, {
    }, function(response){
    $('.echotest').append(response);
    });
```

POST method is now being executed once. although i cant really explain technically why it worked.